# When does $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ bounded and smooth imply that $f$ is Lipschitz?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Under which hypotheses does the condition that $f$ is bounded and smooth imply that $f$ is Lipschitz?

Comment: I guess $|f'(x)| \le K$ for some constant $K > 0$.

Comment: @DeepSea That is basically the definition of Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: @Rene The definition?

Comment: Forget boundedness of $f.$ If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, then $f$ is Lipschitz on $\mathbb R$ iff $\sup_{\mathbb R} |f'| < \infty.$

Comment: All I can think of that uses the fact that $f$ is bounded is a derivative interpolation inequality - if you assume also that $f''$ is bounded then you get that $f'$ is bounded.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis what's the derivative interpolation inequality?

Comment: @zhw. I'm looking for some other condition.

Answer (score 2):

Set $n=1,p,q,r=\infty, j=1, m=2,\alpha=1/2$ in the [Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality) and you get $$|f'| \le \sqrt{\sup |f| \sup |f''|},$$

so $f$ is Lipschitz if it is bounded with bounded second derivative. (There should be an elementary proof of this special case, but I don't have the time to work it out right now.)

Comment: This is not really what I hoped for, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Cool fact!  I've never heard of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality before!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately *no*.  Consider the following extremely contrived example:
\begin{align}
&f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
\\
&x\mapsto \begin{cases}
0 &: x \leq 0\\
\sqrt{x} &:  x \in (0,1)\\
\sin(x-1) +1 &: x \geq 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then, $f'(0)=0$ and $f'(1)=1$, $f(0)=0$, and $f(1)=1$.  Therefore, $f$ is indeed of class $C^1$.

**Note:**
Since you did not accept "Anthony Carapetis"'s answer...then I assume by smooth you mean only once differentiable (as opposed to infinitely differentiable).  Since in the latter case, the result follows from their argument.